# Worker processing multiple job types in Kue

Tags: node.js, queue, kue

I am just investigating Kue as a job processor.  However I am stuck with one concept:

Say I have multiple workers, all can process 1 of 2 job types.

Code looks something like this:

```
queue.process("job1", 1, (job, done) => {
    console.log("processing job 1")
})
queue.process("job2", 1, (job, done) => {
    console.log("processing job 2")
})
```

The idea is that the service will check all queues and start the highest priority jobs.  But I don't want to process more than one job type in parrallel on each worker.

The problem with this is that if a "job1" and a "job2" are added to the queue at the same time, the above process will start both in parrallel.

In reality I will have "N" job types, each with configurable parrallel runs.  I don't want a separate process per job type, as this will be hard to scale.  Each process should be able to handle any job type.

**How can I make sure that only 1 batch of job types will be processed at a time by any one worker?**

Answer (score 2):

One way around this is to only have a single queue job type, but specify a job type within the data you pass to a job and process based on that.

```
queue.create('alljobs', {type: 'jobType1'});
queue.create('alljobs', {type: 'jobType2'});

queue.process('alljobs', 1, (job, done) => {
  if(job.data.type === 'jobType1') {
    console.log("processing job 1");
  } else if(job.data.type === 'jobType2') {
    console.log("processing job 2");
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks, had realised this.  But then you loose the benefits of the UI projects and other aspects.  I've since gone with `agenda` which has similar functionality, but is much more inline with what i need